# Facebook Sharing Debugger gives Error when using CloudFlare Page Rule to redirect to HTTPS

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, redirect, https, cloudflare

I have a site that recently switched over to HTTPS.  To redirect the HTTP to HTTPS, I created a Page Rule in CloudFlare:

```
http://www.domain.com/*
Always Use HTTPS
```

This works and entering the HTTP version of the site redirects to the HTTPS version.

However, this change made the site lose the Facebook "Likes" of the original HTTP version.

To fix that, I followed [Facebook's "moving URLs" instructions](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls) and added the `og:url` meta tag to the HTTPS site with the original HTTP domain to capture the original Likes:

```
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.domain.com"/>
```

However, when re-scraping the site on the [Facebook Sharing Debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/), Facebook gives me an error saying:

```
Could Not Follow Redirect Path
Using data from https://www.domain.com/ because there was an error following the redirect path.

Could Not Follow Redirect
URL requested a HTTP redirect, but it could not be followed.
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Facebook's docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs#moving-urls) state that

> ... the old URL still renders a document with Open Graph tags and
>   returns a HTTP 200 response, at least when loaded by Facebook's
>   crawler. If you want other clients to redirect when they visit the
>   URL, you must send your 301 HTTP response to all non-Facebook crawler
>   clients. The old URL should contain its own og:url tag that points to
>   itself.

ie, http://www.domain.com/ still needs to be accessible by the Facebook Crawler , so redirecting to HTTPS at the CloudFlare level might be a problem.

Instead of redirecting to HTTPS at CloudFlare, you could try creating a .htaccess file at the root of your site with:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(Facebot|facebookexternalhit/1.1) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

If it works, Facebook Crawlers would see the HTTP version of your site and everyone else would be redirected to HTTPS

Good luck!